# windows visual studio, how to debug c++ program like gdb or lldb (no GUI, only command line)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-c++, clang

In linux, you compile a bunch of cpp files and then debug it

```
gcc -g *.cpp
gdb main.o
```

or

```
clang -g *.cpp
lldb main.o
```

That's it.

What's the equivalent of this easy thing in Windows?

In Windows SDK, you can use clang too,

```
clang -g *.cpp
```

But there is no lldb.
There is a lldb.exe, but it seems it's fake.
[image]

I also heard cdb.exe, but no document about how to use it.

Comment: Check out `windbg`.

Comment: Visual Studio is not a command line tool (very much not so). Why do you want to debug in CLI then ?

Comment: The docs for cdb.exe are literally the first hit on you favorite search engine. How much research did you put into this ?

Comment: Just curious: Why are you trying to do this? You apparently have Visual Studio installed, so why not just use its graphical debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cdb.exe` is the command line version of `WinDbg` (or rather WinDbg is the GUI version for cdb). For i guess historical reasons, there's also `ntsd.exe`, which is the same thing as `cdb.exe`. These are all part of the Debugging Tools for Windows toolkit from Microsoft. 
More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-cdb-and-ntsd

The Visual Studio Debugger can at least be started from the command line if you so desire: `devenv /debugexe MyApplication.exe` 
As this is not its intended use, i would expect mixed results here. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/debugexe-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022

Lastly, there is a windows version of `gdb` available as part of `MinGW`, which it turn is the windows port of the GCC compiler.